# Pidgeonhole principle - I'd like an explanation for this answer

Tags: combinatorics, circles

A friend of mine showed me how to solve this question:

suppose there are 5 black dots drawn on a blue sphere. show that there is a closed hemisphere such that 4 of the black points are in it.

his solution: Draw a great circle (a circle with the radius of the sphere) connecting 2 of the black dots, now you have a partition of the ball to 2 hemisphere, and you have 3 dots left, according to pidgeonhole there is a hemisphere with 2 of the dots, if you add that 2 on the circle (boundary is allowed, since its a closed hemisphere) then 2+2=4.

What I don't understand is: Why can we assume that such a great circle exists? Maybe I drew the 5 dots in such a manner that no great circle passes through 2 of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the center of your sphere along with chosen two points to draw a plane. This plane divides your sphere into two great hemispheres.

Comment: This is a good way to find the great circle.

Answer (score 1):

Almost like the plane, where there is a line through any two points, there is a great circle through any two points on the sphere.  The difference is that if the two points are opposite ends of a diameter there are many great circles through them.  For this proof, any one works.  You can take any pair of points as the ones the great circle passes through.